Why does this .c file have two variables with same identifier in the same translation unit?
The miniz compression library which is like an implementation of the zlib compression algorithm is here inside the miniz-3.0.2.zip archive as a pair of .h and .c files:

Usage
Releases are available at the releases
page as a pair of
miniz.c/miniz.h files which can be simply added to a project.

However if I try to compile miniz.c I get the error:
Error   C2086   'const mz_uint s_tdefl_num_probes[11]': redefinition

This is compiling on Visual Studio.
And if we look inside the .c file it has a variable:
static const mz_uint s_tdefl_num_probes[11];

And then further down in the file we have:
static const mz_uint s_tdefl_num_probes[11] = { 0, 1, 6, 32, 16, 32, 128, 256, 512, 768, 1500 };

Was this a mistake a on the author's part?

What is the rationale behind tentative definitions in C? is what I believe is happening. It probably compiles fine with gcc/clang, but msvc isn't a very standard compliant C compiler.

IIRC, MS's C compiler is [mostly] a C++ compiler. Under linux, if I compile with gcc, things are fine. If I compile with g++, I do get the error: redefinition of ‘const mz_uint s_tdefl_num_probe. And, I also get: error: uninitialized const ‘s_tdefl_num_probes’ [-fpermissive] I'm not familiar with MS's C compiler, but gcc et. al. have options like -xc to force the file to be interpreted as C (and not C++), regardless of the file extension. As people here are [overly] fond of saying: "C and C++ are different languages" ;-)

@Zebrafish, " if I try to compile miniz.c " --> are you sure you are using a C compiler and not a C++ one?

Can't reproduce with latest MSVC. I can reproduce with MSVC++ however. Voting to close this as non-reproducible/simple typo (likely wrong compiler used).

It really does depend on which version of Visual Studio you are using.  The following will build on both gcc and VS2019.  I haven't got access to earlier compilers
#include <stdio.h>

// Empty first
static const int emptyfirst[4];
static const int emptyfirst[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

// Full first
static const int fullfirst[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
static const int fullfirst[4];

// A second initialization gives an error
//static const int emptyfirst[4] = {4, 3, 2, 1};

// Third declaration
static const int fullfirst[4];
static const int emptyfirst[4];

int main()
{
    printf("%d empty first\n", emptyfirst[0]);
    printf("%d full first\n", fullfirst[0]);
}

It depends on the file extension and the compiler options.  On Visual studio, the file extension has to be .c
Properties => Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Advanced => Compile As should be Default.
Alternatively, set it to /TC.  That will compile all source code as C.  If you set it to /TP, it will compile as C++, and you will get errors.

I have also tested it on MS Visual Studio 2017 and the behavior is the same. It compiles as a .c file but does not compile as a .cpp file. Therefore, I agree that OP was probably attempting to compile C code as C++.
